# Why did Rob Lowe exit The West Wing?

Tags: casting, the-west-wing

Why did Rob Lowe's character exit *The West Wing* towards the end of Season 4? Specifically is there any documented reasoning behind the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rob Lowe decided to leave the show after a dispute about salary.

See these articles reporting this at the time:

- [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/story?id=101202&page=1)
- [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2002/SHOWBIZ/TV/07/24/west.wing.lowe/index.html)
- [Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/article/2002/08/09/what-really-made-rob-lowe-quit-west-wing/)